# What type should I use to store binary UUID values?

Tags: cassandra, binary, uuid

I have a binary 16 UUID like this:

```
<Buffer 11 ed a7 28 25 a2 57 40 80 61 81 ed 9d 30 12 8e>
```

That comes from using this [binary-uuid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/binary-uuid) library in NodeJS.

What type should I use while creating my table schema in Cassandra?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question directly, binary data can be stored in a CQL `blob` type.

However, it's not clear to me whether (a) your use case really stores binary UUIDs, or (b) you are using *artificial IDs* as the partition key.

If it's (b) then I would recommend using *natural IDs*. For example, if you have a table of users then use usernames or email addresses. They are much better than using artificial IDs. Cheers!

Comment: I am trying to add an `id` column to my rows as a primary key like what MongoDB does automatically using UUID or MySQL does with `id AUTO INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY`

Comment: I am also creating it using the following NodeJS library to prevent database overhead/extra processing of using builtin `uuid()` function. https://www.npmjs.com/package/binary-uuid

Answer (score 1):

Cassandra works with UUID rather than sequences or integer auto increments. The reason comes from the distributed nature of Cassandra, you want a node to generate a new randomized number without having to lock other nodes.

So [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) is an official type of CQL you want to use in your design.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS something_by_id (
   uid        uuid,
   name       text
   PRIMARY KEY ((uid))
);
```

How to use it with NodejS ?

- Import the cassandra drivers: `npm install cassandra-driver`
- Import the type in your file `const Uuid = require('cassandra-driver').types.Uuid;`
- Use it `const id = Uuid.random();`

More details can be found [here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/nodejs-driver/4.6/features/datatypes/uuids/). Note the double parenthesis in the table definition. It is important to understand how a primary is built with Cassandra with its 2 parts partition keys and clustering clumns not serving the same purpose.

Comment: I didn't know there is a function in `cassandra-driver` that produces `binary-uuid`. So what is the difference between `blob` and `uuid` types when we define a table schema?